# trying to get specific values from dictionary of data using JSON and WebSocket. ERROR: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, json, websocket

> Error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

This is weird because I have json.loads which converts the incoming web socket data to a dictionary. I'm trying to grab specific keys&values from the stream of data to perform analysis with.

This is the code:

```
import requests
import datetime
import threading
import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi
from websocket import create_connection
import simplejson as json
import pprint


#Global Variables
current_tick = None
previous_tick = None

#Account info
api_key = '***********************************'
secret_key = '******************************************************'
base_url = 'wss://stream.data.alpaca.markets/v1beta1/crypto'

ws = create_connection(base_url) #Established connection
print(json.loads(ws.recv())) #Prints Connection Message

#connection
auth_message = {"action":"auth", "key": api_key, "secret": secret_key}
ws.send(json.dumps(auth_message))

#subscription
subscription = {"action":"subscribe","trades":["BTCUSD"]} 
ws.send(json.dumps(subscription))
print(json.loads(ws.recv())) #Prints Connection Message

#data Prints
def data():
    while True:
        data = json.loads(ws.recv()) #Prints Connection Message
        global current_tick, previous_tick
        previous_tick = current_tick
        current_tick = data
        print("Sold: ", current_tick['s'])

data()
```

Comment: Where is the error being thrown exactly? I'm assuming it is on `current_tick['s']`, is that right? What does the JSON look like that the server is sending you when the failure occurs? Maybe the JSON is an array (`[...]`) rather than an object (`{...}`)? Your loop is not printing `data`, like you do on all of the earlier calls to `json.loads()`

Comment: yes on current ticks. Data looks like {"S": "BTCUSD", "P": 27000.987, ............}, earlier data seems to match this pattern.